# Weak Solution for Cauchy Problem of Burgers Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider

$\begin{cases}
u_y+uu_x=0\\
u(x,0)=h(x) \tag{1}
\end{cases}$

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
 1 &, x\leq 0 \\
 1-\frac{x}{\alpha} & ,0 \leq x \leq \alpha\\
 0 &, x\geq \alpha
\end{cases}$$

whereas $x$ is the spatial coordinated, and $y$ is the time.

The critical time is $y_c=\alpha$

For the classical solution i.e. $y\in [0,\alpha)$, we use the M.o.C on each of the three cases and get

$$
u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1 &, x\leq y\\
\frac{\alpha-x}{\alpha-y} &, y\leq x \leq \alpha \\
0 &, x\geq \alpha
\end{cases}\tag{2}
$$

Now the weak part comes into play. So we basically look for a shock wave using Rankine-Hugoniot.

$\gamma'(y)=\frac{f(u^+)-f(u^{-})}{u^+-u^-}=\frac{1}{2}\tag{3}$

So we integrate this and get

$\gamma(y)=\frac{1}{2}y+C \tag{4}$

By the condition that the shock starts at the point $(\alpha, \alpha)$ we get $C=\frac{\alpha}{2}$. So we can write down the weak solution: (for $y\in [\alpha,\infty)$

$$
u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1 &, x < \gamma(y) \\
0 &, x > \gamma(y)
\end{cases}\tag{5}
$$

out overall solution is:

$$
u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1 &, x\leq y, y\in[0,\alpha)\\
\frac{\alpha-x}{\alpha-y} &, y\leq x \leq \alpha , y\in[0,\alpha)\\
0 &, x\geq \alpha , y\in[0,\alpha)\\
1 &, x < (y+\alpha)/2, y\in [\alpha, \infty) \\
0 &, x>(y+\alpha)/2, y \in [\alpha, \infty)
\end{cases}\tag{2}
$$

I don't 100% understand how we know that the shock wave starts at $(\alpha, \alpha)$ or rather: To get $C$ in $\gamma$ I need a point I can plug into $\gamma$ - how do I usually get this point (in this case $(\alpha, \alpha)$)?

Comment: From the denominator of Eq. (2), the breaking time is $y=\alpha$. From the solution's cases in Eq. (2), we know that it corresponds to the abscissa $x=\alpha$.